# Ошибка в коде. Помогите найти!

Tags: python

Помогите, пожалуйста, вот код:

```
x = int(input('Введите число: '))
sum_res = 1
start = 1
for number in range(start, 64, start * 2 + 1):
  res = (x - number)
  sum_res = sum_res * res
print(sum_res)
```

Нужен результат по формуле: res = (x - 1) * (x - 3) * (x - 7) * (x - 15)...... (x - 63)

В чем я ошибся?

Comment: Ну так с виду шаг у `range`  должен быть просто `2`, а не `start * 2 + 1`

Comment: @CrazyElf я прогнал этот range, не понятно как формируется шаг. Я нашел 2 различных закономерности формирования ряда (1,3,7,15...63) и там не увеличение на двойку и точно не то, что имеет ТС. Короче, не охота разбираться дальше. ТС, дайте пояснений, чтоб не гадать

Comment: Догадка, шаг формируется так `2^n - 1`?

Comment: не start*2, а start**2. Взял бы да выписал, все что у тебя там получается и стало бы понятно

Comment: @Эникейщик тогда там минус один должен быть

Comment: @Dmitry да там много чего должно быть и не должно быть. Начать с того, что диапазон неправильный. Я же о том, что число - степень двойки минус 1.

Comment: @Эникейщик или вот это подразумевается `(1*2)+1=7, (7*2)+1=15, (15*2)+1=31` у ТС. )

Comment: @Dmitry да, это подразумевалось)) (1*2)+1=7, (7*2)+1=15, (15*2)+1=31 прошу вас не позорьте. я только начинаю

Comment: @Эникейщик вообще конечно так отвечать человеку, который меньше недели с нуля программирование изучает - странно.  "да там много чего должно быть и не должно быть" - уж лучше тогда объяснить, почему диапазон не правильный и что не так. или не отвечать уж тогда.

Comment: @Джуша Даже в мыслях не было. Это неодназначность, я гадал. Ответ посмотрите, должен работать как надо

Comment: @Dmitry, спасибо большое!

Comment: @Джуша на здоровье. Обратите внимание на [Справку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking), когда будете следующий вопрос задавать. Там есть вся практическая информация по данной теме.

Comment: @Джуша А с чего вы взяли, что Dmitry меньше недели с нуля изучает программирование?

Comment: @Эникейщик в общем. я понял, почему не работает шаг и при -1. вот блин, тяжело быть тупым(

Comment: @Джуша именно поэтому я вас в справку отправляю. Если бы вы задавали вопрос с примерами входных данных и ожидаемым результатом и смогли описать все это, то на этом этапе уже нашли ошибку. Это не тупость, но отсутствие опыта

Comment: @Dmitry, понятно, спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Коли нет обратной связи от ТС, брошу здесь это

Формирование членов ряда у вас не верно. Вы получаете не то, что указано в формуле. Мои предположения по этому поводу в виде кода

```py
lst_ = []
start = 1
while True:
    lst_.append(start)
    start = start * 2 + 1
    if start > 64:
        break
```

Можно это написать короче.

Далее сам подсчет

```py
sum_res = 1
for item in lst_:
    sum_res *= (x - item)
```

При `x` равному одному из членов `lst_` результат будет превращаться в ноль. Крайние случаи, которые должны быть учтены